# Monte-carlo simulation code - simple exercise

Tags: python, performance, random, statistics, simulation

I created a quick monte-carlo simulation which seems to do what I want (simple version below). The code basically simulates a Poisson distribution, say this results in a simulation of `10`. it would then simulate `10` values from a lognormal distribution. It then applies two parameters to the results of that simulation, `lim` and `xs`, sums up the results and then stores it in a results matrix. The code then takes the mean of each simulation.

```
import numpy as np
import os
import scipy.stats as sp

sigma = 0.5
u = 10
mu = 100


no_sim = int(10e3)
no_col = 2
mat_res = np.zeros((no_sim,no_col)) #results matrix holder

lim = 40e3 # parameter 1 - needs to vary
xs = 2000 # parameter 2 - needs to vary


for i in range(1,no_sim):
    no_clm = sp.poisson.rvs(mu=mu,size=1)
    clm_sev = sp.lognorm.rvs(s=sigma,scale=np.exp(u),size=no_clm)
    
    temp_mat = np.zeros((np.size(clm_sev),2)) # temp matrix for calculations
    
    temp_mat[:,0] = clm_sev
    temp_mat[:,1] = np.minimum(lim,np.maximum(0,temp_mat[:,0]-xs)) #want to expand this step for various values of lim and xs, e.g. 5 different options
    
    
    mat_res[i,0] = np.sum(temp_mat[:,0])
    mat_res[i,1] = np.sum(temp_mat[:,1])
    
    

#want these mean values for various different lim and xs values which are predefined
print("mean 1 is %s" % np.mean(mat_res[:,0]),
      "mean 2 is %s" % np.mean(mat_res[:,1]))
```

I am trying to do two things:

1. Speed up the code. I will need to run over a million simulations in reality so want to do this in the best way possible - currently it takes a five minutes or so to run a million simulations
2. Expand the code in an efficient way so that I can vary the parameters `lim` and `xs` and get a new result - i.e. right now I have `lim = 40e3` and `xs = 2000`

but I would also want to run it with say `lim = 50e3` and `xs = 1000` and then return back the mean value in the print (along with the original mean for the original `lim` and `xs` parameters). One solution is to wrap the for-loop into a function with the parameters I require, however as I only use the `lim` and `xs` parameters in one line in the monte carlo simulation I don't think it's efficient to run the whole simulation again from scratch, but I can't think of any good way to build it into the for-loop as it stands.

Comment: Please show the format that your "various different `lim` and `xs`" are in. An ndarray?

Comment: @Reinderien I don't have them at the moment, I was going to set them up in a dataframe or an array; but I was trying to plan how to build an inner loop to go through each element systematically and couldn't think of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sigma`, `mu` and `u` should be capitalised because they're constant (if they remain as constant globals; however, in my suggested code I show them instead as function parameters that are lower-case).

Move your simulation out of the global namespace into a function.

Consider adding numerical tests. I have only shown a regression test and cannot vouch for its accuracy. For this to work you need to send a constant seed to Numpy's random generator.

Don't overabbreviate `simulation` to `sim` or `column` to `clm`. I do not know what `sev` stands for.

Don't create a `temp_mat` - you don't need it.

Your main, outer `for` loop is tricky to vectorise, because - due to `no_clm` - your inner arrays are jagged. You can work around this by populating a fully square matrix and then zeroing out partial rows parametrically.

Fundamentally, you cannot represent `mat_res` as a matrix with two columns, because the first result variable is non-parametric and the second one is parametric, so they will have different shapes.

Don't use `zeros` - everywhere that you've used it, `empty` is more appropriate.

To parametrise the way you want, make `lim` and `xs` three-dimensional arrays where two of the dimensions are size-1; have `clm_sev` be a three-dimensional array where the non-1 dimension is in a different position. Then, most operations in Numpy that combine the two will use broadcasting. The first part of a Monte Carlo function could be to assert that these parameter arrays are of the same length, and reshape them to be suitable for broadcasting.

Don't use `min` and `max`; use `clip`.

Your `range(1,`  doesn't seem correct to me - you were skipping your first row and leaving it zero, executing one fewer case than you specified, and skewing your mean. Just let it start from 0.

### Suggested

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp


def monte_carlo(
    lim: np.ndarray,
    xs: np.ndarray,
    sigma: float = 0.5,
    u: float = 10,
    mu: float = 100,
    n_simulations: int = 1000,
) -> tuple[np.float64, np.ndarray]:
    # Put the parameters into shapes usable by our broadcasting
    lim = lim.reshape((1, 1, -1))
    xs = xs.reshape((1, 1, -1))
    n_parameters = lim.shape[-1]

    # Assert that the parameter lengths are the same
    if xs.shape[-1] != n_parameters:
        raise ValueError('Parameter shape mismatch')

    # Column-vector, for each simulation, of simulation row widths
    n_columns = sp.poisson.rvs(mu=mu, size=(n_simulations, 1, 1))

    # The maximum width of any simulation
    width = n_columns.max()

    # Row-vector of simple indices over the width of the simulation matrix
    x_index = np.arange(width)[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]

    # "Sev" (whatever that is) of random values, one row per simulation
    sev = sp.lognorm.rvs(s=sigma, scale=np.exp(u), size=(n_simulations, width, 1))

    # Zero out any simulation value beyond the Poisson-determined width
    sev[x_index >= n_columns] = 0

    # Parametric clipping will yield a three-dimensional matrix: n_simulations * width * n_parameters
    clipped = np.clip(a=sev - xs, a_min=0, a_max=lim)

    result_1 = sev.sum(axis=1).mean()
    result_2 = clipped.sum(axis=1).mean(axis=0)

    return result_1, result_2


def test() -> None:
    np.random.seed(0)  # to reproduce the same results
    lim = np.linspace(start=38e3, stop=42e3, num=5)
    xs = np.linspace(start=1800, stop=2200, num=5)
    mean_1, mean_2 = monte_carlo(lim, xs)

    tol = {'rtol': 0, 'atol': 1e-8}
    assert np.isclose(mean_1, 2505180.2094949023, **tol)
    assert np.all(
        np.isclose(
            mean_2,
            (
                2177820.61316294,
                2180250.94121704,
                2181574.66242172,
                2181868.23243192,
                2181257.68169412,
            ),
            **tol,
        )
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: thank you very much for this. I did not know about broadcasting so that was useful. What is parameter fixing? Your link in the post goes to a poisson distribution. Speed wise, I assume there is no other way to speed it up for high level of sims (1m+)? Thank you again

Comment: From that page, _Alternatively, the distribution object can be called (as a function) to fix the shape and location. This returns a “frozen” RV object holding the given parameters fixed. Freeze the distribution and display the frozen `pmf`: [...]_

Comment: Sorry missed that. What's the logic behind freezing it - it seems to return the same result, is it speed related?

Comment: I don't know whether the speedup is going to be significant, but it's the most logical thing to do to define your parameters once instead of passing them every time

Comment: Understood thanks. To speed it up any further, would multiprocessing be the next thing to look into?

Comment: Yes, that would help; I'm writing a separate SO question on a vectorisation detail before giving you another suggestion.

Comment: excellent - thank you, look forward to it.

Comment: @lmkir99 See edit. The workaround is to use fully square matrices and then selectively zero out. This is vectorised. Of course it uses a lot more memory.

Comment: this is brilliant thanks. Do you have any resource on learning more about broadcasting and multidimensional arrays? Learned a lot just working through your code, but most of it was new to me! thanks again.

Comment: Nothing specific, other than: never write this kind of code without stepping through in a debugger and looking at the results; if you see something on the internet - which is increasingly polluted with opportunistic SEO junk "tutorials" - always back it up with the official reference documentation.